# Programatically loading fonts, textures, and media in XNA

Tags: xna, c#, assets

So far, in my rhythm game, I've been using XNA's Content Pipeline for loading static resources in my app (videos, sound effects, etc). However, down the road I'd want to allow users to create their own themes, as well as making custom notecharts for whatever songs they'd like to play. Is there any way to load say, a Texture2D or Video object, from disk without using the Content Pipeline, given a file path to the resource?

**EDIT**: Even thought this is XNA, I'm targeting Windows only (no Zune, WP7, or Xbox 360).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Texture2D.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196945%28XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx) method; for the first parameter, give it your `GraphicsDevice` which is a property of the `Game` class (so from within a method of the Game class, just use `this.GraphicsDevice`).

Unfortunately only `Texture2D` objects can be loaded this way; [a `Video` object is not so easy to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949264/how-to-load-a-video-from-file-in-xna-pc-only).

Comment: Dang, loading audio and video at runtime are going to be critical in my app down the road, so this is bad news.

Comment: Not all hope is lost though! Look at the second answer to the linked question; looks like you can compile and run a video or audio at runtime, with XNA 3.1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949264/how-to-load-a-video-from-file-in-xna-pc-only/2008784#2008784

Comment: @Ricket Yeah, I can't have users be forced to download GS just to be able to compile these, so I'm still stuck. I'm trying to look into the DirectShow VideoPlayer, but it's old and finicky.

Comment: But... they need to have XNA installed whether it's 3.1 or 2.0, right? What's the difference?

Comment: The XNA Runtime is always needed, yes (if I recall correctly). However, that MSBuild method requires the **entire** Game Studio to be downloaded on the user's computer (and GS 4.0 is about a 400 MB ISO).

Comment: On top of that, I believe the full game studio requires the full .net framework insted of the client profile which the redist requires.

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely possible to run the content build process at runtime using MSBuild.  The following sample shows you basically how to do it:  http://creators.xna.com/en-GB/sample/winforms_series2.  This particular example uses windows forms, but there is nothing preventing you from doing the same thing in an actual game.

The big problem is that the content pipeline assembly (which is where all the processors/importers/build tasks necessary for building are) is not included in the XNA Framework redistributable.  This means that in order to actually create and/or load custom content your users would need to install whatever version of XNA Game Studio your game was built with.  They would never need to actually use any of the software included in it, but they would need to install it.  Depending on your game and who you expect to be creating and using custom content this may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: If only it didn't require installing XNA GS on the user's computer, this would have been perfect.

Comment: It's certainly unfortunate.  I remember seeing rumblings some time ago (years) about the XNA Team wanting to get the Content Pipeline stuff into the redist, but it hasn't happened in the last few versions and it seems unlikely to happen soon given their current focus on non-PC platforms where the pipeline won't run anyway.

Comment: Makes sense, although yeah, it kinda sucks for PC-only XNA games.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the content processors expose classes which do a lot of the heavy lifting, e.g. take in a Stream and produce an intermediate object (like the data necessary to construct a mesh, but not an actual Mesh object).  You may be able to do some additional processing to transform the intermediate object into the final object that you want to consume.  Some of those classes may actually even spit out the final object for you.  It varies by the type of content.  I suggest digging through the content processors for the relevant content types and see anything useful is exposed.  You may have to rewrite some bits yourself (Reflector is your friend), but it could be worth the effort if you really don't want to use "precompiled" assets.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations and/or links to examples? It seems like the only media type I'm lacking the ability to import now is video, and IIRC it's one of the two that is considered infeasible to load manually.